Authentication failed for local sonar setup
I am setting up sonarqube in my local mac machine using homebrew. The installation is successful but when login with default admin/admin credentials it throws Authentication failed.
Sonarqube version - 10.4.1
Sonar-scanner version - 5.0.1
Java - Tested with both 17/11
Any help would be appreciated.
